# "... advanced through the passes ...," meaning in the following context

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

What's the meaning of "advanced through the passes" in the following sentence?

> On landing at Bombay, I learned that my corps had advanced through the
> passes, and was already deep in the enemy's country.

It's from the *A Study in Scarlet* by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. I couldn’t find any answer yet. I hope, you could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is literal.  A "pass" is a gap between two summits in the mountains.

The corps (a group of soldiers) has advanced (gone forward) [from Bombay to Kandahar] through a mountainous region, probably Northern Balochistan.